# package has corrupted project

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I installed this package which has corrupted my project I have removed the package completely from the composer.json file and done a composer update I also have removed any code that references that package and I'm still getting this error

```
FatalErrorException in
50315282edd449c1ae6f735378f3cdd304559dde.php line 93:
Class 'Share' not found
```

chencha/share errors Share class not found:

Provider

```
Chencha\Share\ShareServiceProvider::class,
```

Alias:

```
'Share' => Chencha\Share\ShareFacade::class,
```

Comment: Looks like a cache file to me.  Did you clear the laravel cache?

Comment: I've cleared the cache and cleared compiled

Comment: did you clear view cache ? `php artisan view:clear` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you actually deleted all references to the package then it can be a cache problem.

Try:

> composer dump-autoload && php artisan clear-compiled

Comment: I added this package and it says it doens't know that class "Share" https://github.com/prodeveloper/social-share I use this class in my page like so {{ Share::(.....)->twitter() }} shouldn't that work

Comment: If you did this: *composer require chencha/share* you had to update the service provider array and register the alias as they instruct in the Readme. Did you do that?

Comment: Yeah I did that. I'm using Laravel 5.2 and it doesn't say it's only for laravel 5.0 or 5.1 so I can't see any issue

Comment: How can I re download a new copy of that package without using it from my cache

Comment: Checkout my update to my question I have add the provider and alias correctly what do you think is up

Comment: Check storage/logs/laravel.log the latest entry to see exactly what's wrong